# How to add a Client App to another GSuite Company?

Tags: gmail-api, google-workspace

I've developed an application that works through Google's GSuite using OAuth2. The app is working fine and is part of the GSuite account that was set up to allow testing while developing it (which is the owning account of the app in the Developer Console). However, I now want to give the app to another GSuite company but can't see how to get them to add it?

The application has been submitted for review with Google to get it added via the Marketplace but we're keen to get the second company using it ASAP. I've had a look through the Google docs but couldn't find anything that appeared relevant and even tried to see if I could find an existing question on here. If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: You won't be able to give it to another company until it's published, so if the review is taking linger than expected, your best is to contact Google [GSuite support](https://gsuite.google.com/support/?referral-tabs_activeEl=g-suite-and-gcp).

Comment: Thanks @ziganotschka I've quoted it as the answer and will accept it in the next 21 hours when it's possible to do so

Comment: This was just a suggestion rather than a denitive solution. Also, according to the Stackoverflow guidelines you should only write (and accept) an answer yourself if you found the solution yourself. Maybe after hearing back from GSuite support you will have more information about the root cause of the delay and post that information as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

> You won't be able to give it to another company until it's published, so if the review is taking linger than expected, your best is to contact Google GSuite support